# Best way of adding a simple blog to a website?

Tags: blogs

I'm developing a site and I want it to have a very simple blog page. What are the best options to add in a blog to the site? blogger/wordpress seem like overkill, as I just want to be able to do simple posts and allow people to comment, are there any recommened blog scripts that I could use? I don't mind it being commercial as long as there's no branding on it. The site is being developed in Xhtml, Css, Jquery, Php, mysql.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use Wordpress, I know it may seem to have over-bloat for your needs, but you never know when your needs change/expand so having a good base system for this is a good place to be.

You can strip out and hide a lot of Wordpress functionality through simple extensions if you wish the UI to be more simple. It's not the worlds #1 blogging software for no reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

A great alternative to wordpress is [b2evo](http://b2evolution.net/).  Its free, open source and easy to set up and use.